# CRM tool for university institution supporting junior researchers

Tags: encryption, self-hosted, crm, newsletter

We are a new institution supporting junior researchers at a mid-sized university. We are looking for a tool that can

1. keep track of contacts
2. send newsletters to groups of contacts
3. allow people to register for workshops
4. provide a simple feedback option

**Ad 1:** contacts are a) researchers seeking support ("clients"), b) their supervisors and c) external speakers. In addition to contact details we need to store notes on each contact with clients. Possibly also workshops the attended or held.

**Ad 2:** Nothing fancy, but it would be great if newsletters could be sent to sub sets of contacts and if they could subscribe to specific themes. registration and cancellation should work through a web interface.

**Ad 4:** We would like to send emails with a link to a simple online feedback questionaire.

The tool (or tools) needs to be self hosted and provide some sort of encryption, as data we store includes private and sensitive information.

Free/libre would be great, but commercial would not be a problem.

Comment: @HYT depends on which part you focus. For the full spectrum: "Free/libre would be great, but commercial/paid would not be a problem." In that case, mentioning a budget would be advised.

Comment: On this site, we use the [tag:gratis] tag to mean 'free of cost', although I sometimes use those specific words since they are better understood.  If I'm willing to pay for something, I call it commercial, or I just say how much I'm willing to spend (I coined the term *Milkshakeware* if I'm willing to spend about as much as a milkshake). If I want open-source, I use those words. So for your case, your might choose to write "Gratis (free of cost) would be great, but commercial up to XYZ amount would not be a problem."  I see your recent edit is close to that, so I think you did a great job. :-)